# How to event.target a form's name which is an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, post

I have a few checkbox that have name let say checkBoxName[]. How do I read the value in it? I submit it to my handleSubmit function and failed to post it using Fetch.

```
  <div>
    <input type='checkbox'  name='checkBoxName[]' value='1'/>
    <input type='checkbox'  name='checkBoxName[]' value='2'/>
    <input type='checkbox'  name='checkBoxName[]' value='3'/>
  </div>
```

In my submit function, I tried this and it didn't work and returned `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`. I used the console.log to see what is being passed back.

```
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target.checkBoxName.value)
    //console.log(event.target.checkBoxName[].value)   //This gives me error, cannot use [] here

    // fetch(............, {
    //   method: "POST",
    //   headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    //   body: JSON.stringify({
    //     checkBox: event.target.checkBoxName.value
    //   })
    // })
    //   .then(response => {
    //     console.log(response);
    //     if (response.status === 200) {
    //       console.log('successfully')
    //     } else {
    //       alert('Check your inputs')
    //     }
    //   })
    //   .catch(error => {
    //     alert('Server error')
    //   });
  }
```

Can someone tell me how to read the value and to post it correctly? Thank you

Edited:  I want to see how the array looks like that is going to be passed to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `event.target.name` to get the name of the element that's firing your event.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you're actually using a form with a proper submit button or if you're just rendering a div with checkboxes. I'm assuming it's the second one.

Here is how you can go about it.

Basically, `event.target` might not work depending on your setup. It would work under the assumption that you checkboxes are a child of the target element. But it doesn't look like that's the case. If this is true, you can just establish a reference to your checkbox container and fetch the name values when they click your button.

```js
const submit = (evt) => {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes input[type="checkbox"]');
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    console.log(inputs[i].getAttribute('name'));
  }
};

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', submit);
```

```html
 <div id="checkboxes">
    <input type='checkbox'  name='checkBoxName[]' value='1'/>
    <input type='checkbox'  name='checkBoxName[]' value='2'/>
    <input type='checkbox'  name='checkBoxName[]' value='3'/>
  </div>
  
  <button id="button">Submit</button>
```